# Swagger dynamic url for documentation with Laravel

Tags: laravel, dynamic, swagger, documentation

I am using swagger(8.0) with Laravel(8.40). Everything is fine but not able to create dynamic url  for the swagger documentation. It always create documentation with http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/docs. I want dynamic host so that I can also share this documentation with others after upload my project on the live server.

Comment: You can add a function in the swagger config file to do that.

Comment: Hi @MarcelSanting thanks for the reply. May you please give me some more detail. I am using swagger with laravel. Please send me the path of the file in which I have to do changes. It will be very helpful if you can share that function also.